# Using vintage lens for Canon EOS 450D

Tags: canon, old-lenses, praktica

I would like to ask for a help. I've recently fell in love with analog photography. My grandfather gave me these cameras: Werra with Tessar (2,8/50) Lens and Praktica PL nova 1 with Oreston 1,8/50 lens. I tried to take photos with them but I found out that analog photography is an expensive business these days. So I wondered if it is possible to attach these lenses to my Canon EOS 450D camera. I found out that they are selling Tessar with canon special eos bayonette on ebay, but I would rather buy only the bayonette/adapter and mod it by myself.

Could anyone please tell me which types (or models) of adapters would suit for my Canon EOS / vintage lenses?

Comment: I think, that my question is way more specific.

Comment: @MjuAddict what makes you think that it is? If the flange distance of your lenses is okay with that of the EF-system (see link from Corey), then you can use adapters (see link from Corey).

Comment: @flolilolilo because the adapter mentioned in his question is meant to replace the bayonet on the lens, not attach to it.

Comment: It's not really an answer to the question, but practically speaking you'll probably be much better off considering a decent 50mm prime lens in the EOS mount. The EF 50mm f/1.8 STM is a bargain. No, it does not have an aperture ring on the lens or the "feel" of an old manual lens, but it does have the same image quality.

Comment: As @MichaelClark said, modern lenses have much better usability - autofocus, aperture control from the body (meaning all automatic and semi-automatic modes are working correctly), EXIF data, and all those benefits are missing with adapted lenses, and EF50/1.8 is downright cheap. If it isn't cheap enough, there's Yongnuo 50/1.8, a copy of that lens for even less money - and both are better than Oreston. Also, Werra does not have interchangeable lens, it is permanently fixed, so removing it would destroy the camera.

Comment: If you love analog photography, don't ask it to be something else! Film photography may be more expensive than digital, but it's not prohibitive -- keep your grandfather's cameras working and shoot a few rolls from time to time. Practice by setting your 450D to M, ISO 100, and leave it there for at least 24 consecutive shots.

Comment: The Praktica lens (Oreston) is probably M42 (Pentax screw mount) mount. The Werra is more problematic, as rangefinders, the flange distance means you probably can't adapt their lenses on any type of SLR, film or digital.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key points from the linked question is that the lens is designed to sit only so far from the film/image sensor.

Rangefinders don't have a reflex mirror, allowing much slimmer camera bodies. Because of this design, lenses can sit relatively close to the film/sensor.

SLR's, by virtue of design (gotta have space for that mirror), locate the lens slightly farther away from the film/sensor.

It is relatively easy to mount an SLR lens on a rangefinder (or mirrorless). The SLR lens is designed to sit farther away from the sensor - so all one has to do when moving it to a rangefinder is provide a spacer equal to the difference between what the lens was designed for and where it will sit on the rangefinder. Like an extension tube.

However, going the other direction is much harder to do. You'll be taking a lens designed to sit, say 35mm from the film plane and putting it on a camera that sits the lens ~44mm from the film plane. (I'm not 100% on these numbers, just an example).

By being pushed out, your focus is going to be greatly off...restrictively off. This means that you need an adapter that has a glass element in it to help focus the light at this newer distance.

The quality of that adapter glass follows all of the same rules that we judge lenses by. Except finding excellent adapters is much harder than finding excellent lenses.

Because of this, even if you did re-mount those vintage lenses, they wouldn't give you the same look and feel to the photo. Trust me, I shoot vintage equipment as well and [know that urge to want to remount things](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94770/canon-ef-to-pentax-645).

But, like Caleb and Micheal Clark have said, you're best bet is to leave these vintage cameras as they are and enjoy them from time to time as budget permits. Get a lens for your dSLR that mirrors the vintage, like the 50mm f/1.8 STM. Learning to shoot this lens on your dSLR *will* improve your ability to shoot with the vintage gear as well.